# Sanitizing, Validating and Escaping in WordPress (Plugin)

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, sanitization, escaping

I am currently developing my first WordPress plugin. A few days ago I submitted it to WordPress for review. Unfortunately, the plugin was not (yet) published, because I still have to close some security issues. More specifically, it is about the fact that data must be Sanitized, Escaped, and Validated.

Unfortunately, I completely forgot about this point during development. Now I have familiarized myself with the above principles via the documentation and I think I have understood them now, however I am still unsure how to apply this practically in some places.

**1. Highlight the active menu item**

To highlight the active menu item I have written a small helper function:

```
protected function get_current_site() {
    $page = $_GET['page'];
    return $page;
}
```

The function is used in the header:

```
<li <?php if($this->get_current_site() == 'myplugin-settings') { echo 'class="active"'; } ?>><a href="?page=myplugin-settings">Settings</a></li>
```

How do I apply the three principles (Sanitized, Escaped, and Validated) here?

**2. Toggle status via AJAX**

To change the status of my plugin I use a small function via AJAX. Here $_POST["active"] contains either 0 or 1:

```
$this->loader->add_action('wp_ajax_toggle_myplugin', $this, 'toggle_myplugin');

public function toggle_myplugin() {
    $active = $_POST["active"];
    $status = update_option('myplugin_status', $active);
    echo $status;
    wp_die();
}
```

How do I apply the three principles (Sanitized, Escaped, and Validated) here?

**3. Dynamic rendering of a template**

I use a GET variable to output a different template on a specific page of my plugin:

```
public function render_template() {
    if(isset($_GET['action'])) {
        $action = $_GET['action'];
        switch($action) {
            case("edit"):
                include MYPLUGIN_ROOT_PATH . 'includes/admin/templates/template1.php';
                break;
            case("add"):
                include MYPLUGIN_ROOT_PATH  . 'includes/admin/templates/template2.php';
                break;
            default:
                include MYPLUGIN_ROOT_PATH  . 'includes/admin/templates/template3.php';
        }
    }
}
```

How do I check the `action` variable?

**4. Check value from an hidden input-field**

I use hidden input-field to pass hidden values (in my case an ID):

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">

public function actions() {
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        $action = $_POST["action"];
        switch($action) {
            case "edit":
                $id = $_POST["id"];
                $name = $_POST["name"];
                [...]
                break;
            case "add":
                $name = $_POST["name"];
                [...]
                break;
    }
}
```

Thank you very much in advance. Please be gracious as this is my first plugin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Now I have familiarized myself with the above principles via the documentation and I think I have understood them now

I don't know which documentation you read, but you should check the [Plugin Security section](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/security/) in the plugin developer's handbook.

And there are three main issues I noticed in your code:

1. Before attempting to use a `$_GET` or `$_POST` variable, you should check whether it's set or not.

   So for example in your `get_current_site()` function, instead of `$page = $_GET['page'];`, you should do:

   ```php
   $page = isset( $_GET['page'] ) ? wp_unslash( $_GET['page'] ) : '';
   ```
2. In your `toggle_myplugin()` function, you should [sanitize](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/security/securing-input/) the option value (prior to updating the option) using functions like [`sanitize_text_field()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_text_field/):

   ```php
   $active = isset( $_POST['active'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['active'] ) : '';
   ```
3. In your hidden input field, you should [escape](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/security/securing-output/) the input value using functions like [`esc_attr()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_attr/). So instead of simply `echo $id;`, you would use `echo esc_attr( $id );`:

   ```html
   <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $id ); ?>">
   ```

So I hope that helps and feel free to ask if you need any clarification, and as the plugin handbook recommends, consider [checking user capabilities](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/security/checking-user-capabilities/) and using [nonces](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/security/nonces/) (checking user's intent) where appropriate in your plugin.

Comment: Thank you, Sally! That really helps me. If I have any more questions, I'll get back to you.